# Hover on anchor does not stay put with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I have anchors (in an unordered list) that I would like to pop up an image in a specific location when hovered over.  The overall container has relative positioning, and the anchor class has absolute positioning, however the images are moving down apparently with each list item instead of being absolutely positioned as expected.

I have tried wrapping the div in an absolute positioned div, but... no.

The goal is to have a list of items that light up a date on a calendar off to the side, however i can't get the image to stay still.

Thanks

CSS:

```
a { text-decoration: none; }


#container {
position:relative;
width:1100px;
height:680px;

margin:0px auto;
font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-size:12px;
z-index:1;
border: 1px solid;}

#container a.pics {position: absolute;}
#container a.pics img.thumb {display:block; border:1px solid #000;}

#container a.pics span {display:none; border:0; border:hidden; text-align:center;}
#container a.pics span img {margin:10px auto; border:1;}

#container a.pics:hover {white-space:normal;}
#container a.pics:hover img.thumb {border:1px solid #fff;}
#container a.pics:hover span {display:block; position:absolute; left:105px; top:0px; z-index:5;}

img#top {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:100px;
border:hidden;
z-index:-1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<ul>
<li><a class="pics" href="#">one<span><img id="top" src="image.jpg" width="30" height="30"></span> </a>     </li>
<li><a class="pics" href="#">two<span><img id="top" src="image.jpg" width="30" height="30"></span> </a>  </li>
<li><a class="pics" href="#">three<span><img id="top" src="image.jpg" width="30" height="30"></span>   </a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Can you please prove http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Your `img` elements must have different `id`s to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `position:absolute` from the `pics` class. Just leave it in its static positioning.

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/zvHuM/1/)

When an element is absolutely positioned, it will position itself relative to the nearest parent with position set to absolute, relative, or fixed.

Comment: I hoped it was something simple.  Thanks @jacelysh.

Answer (score 0):

The absolute behavior is behaving exactly as it should. If I understood what you want, you should use `position:fixed;`

```
img#top{
position:fixed;
left:*/adjust to your needs/*
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/iamjosan/gj6Bt/)